# Почему не запускается tensorflow на python 3.8

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

стоит python 3.9, сам tensorflow запускается из-под python 3.8 в командной строке windows
После py -3.8 и попытки import tensorflow лезет следующая ошибка:

```
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> import tensorlflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorlflow'
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: Произошел сбой в программе инициализации библиотеки динамической компоновки (DLL).

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: Произошел сбой в программе инициализации библиотеки динамической компоновки (DLL).


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions. Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

С чем это может быть связано и что мне делать?

Comment: Вроде Ваша проблема, в ответе есть пошаговое решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54609544/how-to-fix-importerror-dll-load-failed-when-importing-keras

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло!